# VERILOG CODE for Clock Divider

Tags: verilog

I have a ZYBO board with a 125 Mhz clock that am I trying to to bring down to 0.5 Hz in Verilog. Could anyone help me with the code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

125,000,000 / 250,000,000 = 0.5
You will need counter of 27 bits to accommodate half of 250M minus 1

```
reg [26:0] counter;
reg clk_low;

always@(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
    if(!reset) begin
        counter[26:0] <= {27{1'b0}};
        clk_low <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        if(counter[26:0]==27'h773593F) begin
            clk_low <= ~clk_low;
            counter[26:0] <= {27{1'b0}};
        end else counter[26:0] <= counter[26:0] + 1'b1;
    end
end
```